# UITableView content offset of y position always return 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

In `scrollview` delegate method table content offset while scrolling always return 0 for it's y position.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

   print(items:String(format:"Offset %d",scrollView.contentOffset.y))

}
```

I have also printed the `myTableView.contentOffset.y`
But it also prints the same result.

Comment: Describe your problem better. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: I want to get the exact content offset of  `UITableView` while scrolling.

Comment: How many UIScrollView (and subclasses like UITableView, UICollectionView..) do you have in the ViewController?

Comment: are you using a UIViewController or a UITableViewController? Also make sure you're regsitered as the tableView delegate

Comment: @KoustovBasu : String(format:"Offset %f",scrollView.contentOffset.y) NOT %d. Offset y is CGFloat.

Answer (score -2):

`ContentOffset` doesn't change when you scrolling. It's origin of your content in scrollView. It defines the point in the content view that is visible at the top left of the scroll view bounds. We can use this property to scroll programmatically .

There is more about it

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset
>   https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/scroll-view/

Try to track `contenView.bounds.origin.y` for tracking y-position